# Location redirect from domain to another one in nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect locations
`play.example.com/u/<user id>` to `example.com/u/<user id>`
and `play.example.com/b/<game id>` to `play.example2.net/b/<game id>`

While having options for website too (webroot and api which i host on same domain).
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understood your question properly, this should work:

```
server {
  server_name play.example.com;

...

  location ~ ^/u/(.*)$ {
    return 301 $scheme://example.com/u/$1;
  }

  location ~ ^/b/(.*)$ {
    return 301 $scheme://play.example2.net/b/$1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Edited answer, please try it
there is regex in location, you can validate userid and gameid by symbols, at the moment it allow any text after these locations

Comment: It is a good practice to use at least the start anchor `^` in the regular expression: `location ~ ^/u/(.*) {`. The curreent location blocks match `.*/u/`, which is too wide match.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutelly right, i corrected answer, thanks

Comment: Never use a 301 redirect unless you are sure that's what you want to do and it has been thouroughly tested with a temporary redirect (302)

Answer (score 1):

Just this morning was curious how to selectively redirect some but not all paths to another host.

Using the `$request_uri` variable saves us from writing regexes:

```
location /u/ { 
  return 301 $scheme://play.example2.net$request_uri;
}
```

Only requests matching `/u/...` will enter the location block and trigger the `return 301`. This will redirect to the corresponding `/u/...` location on the target host since the `$request_uri` includes the matched location prefix.

The trailing slash in the location is important, as otherwise it would redirect for any path starting with `/u...` like `/user` or `/ultron`. Tho this means it won't redirect requests to naked `/u`.

If you want to redirect the naked `/u` as well, define another location with the `=` prefix:

```
location = /u {
  return 301 $scheme://play.example2.net$request_uri;
}
```

The order of the two locations in the file doesn't matter. Nginx will prioritize match to `= /u` before the others prefixed with `/u...`.